# Finding a regex pattern to find the string ending with a word or continuing

Tags: regex, perl

I am looking for the syntax to find whether there is continuation after a particular word or not.

For example, given the string `"it is very difficult to test code"` I am trying with the pattern

```
/it is (.+) to test ([^/s])$/
```

to find whether the string ends with only one word after test or more words.

If there are more words, then I want no match.

If there is only one word after test, then I need to get that word.

Comment: And what problem are you having with that solution?

Comment: You're already there.  By having a boundary condition `$`, you're already enforcing the most important limitation.  Just need to capture the optional word:  `/it is (.+) to test\s*(\S*)$/`

Answer (score 1):

In the Perl spirit of "there is more than one way to do it", here's two ways of going about solving the problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

sub test_regex {
    my $string = shift @_;
    print "$string: $1\n" if $string =~ /test\s+(\w+)$/;
}

sub test_split {
    my $string = shift @_;
    # split on "test" to get words before and after
    my @div = split "test", $string;
    if (@div == 2) {
        # split on space to get each word
        my @words = split " ", $div[1];
        print "$string: $words[0]\n" if @words == 1;
    }
}

print "Using test_regex:\n";
test_regex "it is very difficult";
test_regex "it is very difficult to test code";
test_regex "it is very difficult to test code like this";

print "\nUsing test_split:\n";
test_split "it is very difficult";
test_split "it is very difficult to test code";
test_split "it is very difficult to test code like this";
```

#### test_regex

- the literal word "test"
- `\s+` one or more number of spaces
- `\S+` one or more non-space characters
- `$` the end of the string

The part between the `( )` is captured and assigned to `$1`. Any number of non-whitespace characters isn't very specific, so you might want use a [different character class](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html), such as `[:alpha:]`, which matches any alphabetical character.

Output:

```
Using test_regex:
it is very difficult to test code: code

Using test_split:
it is very difficult to test code: code
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well your question, you can use this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = "it is very difficult to test code";
if ($string =~ m/^it is (.*?) to test (\S+)$/) {
    #print $1; 1st capture group (very difficult)
     print $2; # 2nd capture group (code)
} else {
    # Match attempt failed
}
```

http://ideone.com/00DJh1

***Explanation:***

```
Assert position at the beginning of the string «^»
Match the characters “it is ” literally «it is »
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(.*?)»
   Match any single character that is not a line break character «.*?»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Match the characters “ to test ” literally « to test »
Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2 «(\S+)»
   Match a single character that is a “non-whitespace character” «\S+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any) «$»
```